# Convert a String back into a Big Decimal Java

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

I have the following code which is underlined in red saying that the assignments wsID - wsIdString are non-convertible.  I understand this as it is trying to assert the value of a BigDecimal Object onto a String.  Just asking how to I convert it so it does get assigned?

Below my code takes the ws.identifier - () gets it as a String, replaces the first 5 numbers with 55555 - so the new value of the ws.identifier begins with 55555 and then tries to put it into back.

```
BigDecimal wsId = ws.getIdentifier();

String wsIdString = String.valueOf(wsId);

wsIdString = wsIdString.replaceFirst(".{5}", "55555");

//Assign wsIdUpd to wsId - below is where is underlined in red

 wsId = wsIdString;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) before asking questions. We expect you to put in a little work before asking questions.

Comment: Listen I am just new here, there is no reason to be soo stuck up.

Comment: I am sorry that you took offense at my comment. I did not mean to offend you. I was simply informing you what this community expects from its user.

Comment: I don't ask many questions as you have probably seen on my profile and usually take the time to read and find things out myself but was in quite a stressful situation where a change had to be made and deployed ASAP - so needed an answer right away - it was a one of!

Comment: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) explains that we would like the asker to research the problem before asking. As it is trivial to find the answer elsewhere (I simply searched ["bigdecimal from string"](https://www.google.com/?#q=bigdecimal+from+string), this question doesn't really add much to the site. As a general rule, when you are having a problem with a specific class (`BigDecimal`), do a google search of "java classname documentation" (so `java BigDecimal documentation`). Go through the page and see if any of those methods answers your question.

Comment: "Being new" is not a reason to think that other people should do your work for you. You could have found the answer to your question in the time it took to write your question in the first place. Please be polite to potential answerers and do your research before asking.

Comment: Both of you and your attitudes exemplify why I rarely use Stack Overflow only in desperate situations.

Comment: I'm sorry that you feel that way about Stack Overflow. The thing is that Stack Overflow, just like other community-oriented sites, has standards, and it's generally disliked if you don't follow them. As pointed out by Quincunx, reading the help center is a good place to start on what the standards here are. In addition, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) is a good checklist to follow for asking good questions.

Comment: I would also like to add that Stack Overflow really isn't that good of a place for "desperate situations", as you have no guarantee as to when or if your question will be answered. Remember, answerers are volunteers that do this in their free time.

Comment: Also, for future reference, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380) answer. It's good that you aren't flooding the place with questions, but try to take care that the questions you ask are good questions.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
wsId = new BigDecimal(wsIdString);
```